# How to create custom delivery options

Tags: shipping, shipping-address

we are close to launching a Magento site but I'm wondering if there is a way to set up custom delivery options, we need to set up the following options:

Standard delivery (UK) (3-5 working days) £4.95
Next day delivery (UK)-Order Weekday Before 12pm £10.00
Next day Saturday delivery (UK)-Order on Weekday Before 12pm £12.00
Furniture Courier-Mainland Only £30.00
Collect In-Store £0.00
£50 or higher free

It doesn't look like this is possible in out the box Magento, if not does anyone know a plugin which will do it?

Thanks

Comment: Not out of the box, but custom carriers are fairly easy to create with your own extension http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple to do with the Matrixrates extension which is totally free.

You might need a paid extn or need to adapt if you need to change the rules based on product group, as it works on destination, weight/price/qty.

It supports multiple shipping method configuration, which tablerates does not.

http://www.webshopapps.com/us/free/matrixrate-shipping-extension.html